# issues in using localstorage in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am trying to create a login page in react using the code->

login.js

```
 axios.get(apiUrl)  
                .then((result) => {  
                    
                    //console.log(result.data);  

                    if (result.data.status === 200)  {
                        // transfer to dashboard page
                        localStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', true);

                        alert(result.data.message);

                        return navigate("/dashboard");
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        
                        alert(result.data.message);
                        return navigate("/login");
                    }
                }
                )
```

now this will add a key-value pair in local storage.

now for my dashboard page i am using a navbar from `'responsive-navbar-react'`

here is the code->

```
const NavbarDashboard = () => {
  const props = {
    items: [
      {
        text: 'Profile',
        link: '/dashboard'
      },
      {
        text: 'Logout',
        link: '/',
      }
    ],
    logo: {
      text: 'logo',
      link: '/dashboard'
    },
    style: {
      barStyles: {
        background: '#444',
        fontFamily: "'Lato', sans-serif",
      },
      sidebarStyles: {
        background: '#222',
        buttonColor: 'white'
      }
    }
  }
  return <Navbar {...props} />
}

export default NavbarDashboard;
```

this works fine. the value is set in local storage. but when i try to use the following code->

```
{
            text: 'Logout',
            link: '/',
onclick: localStorage.removeItem("isLoggedIn")
          }
```

the value is not set in local storage when i try to login.

i want to add logout functionality on the button click. can someone help?

EDIT------------

creating a seperate logout component

```
import React from 'react';

function Logout() {
    let navigate = useNavigate();

    localStorage.removeItem('isLoggedIn')

    return navigate("/");

}


export default Logout;

//end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
{
  text: 'Logout',
  link: '/',
  onclick: localStorage.removeItem("isLoggedIn")
}
```

In this code `localStorage.removeItem("isLoggedIn")` is called immediately

you need to create anonymous function to wrap `localStorage.removeItem("isLoggedIn")`

```js
{
  text: 'Logout',
  link: '/',
  onclick: () => localStorage.removeItem("isLoggedIn")
}
```

Logout component

```js
import React from "react"
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom"

const Logout = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.removeItem("isLoggedIn")
    }, [])
    
    return <Navigate to="/" />
}
```

```js
{
  text: 'Logout',
  link: '/logout'
}
```

Entry component

```js
<Route path="/logout" element={<Logout/>}>
```

Comment: yes now it is saving the value but when i click on the button, it is not getting deleted

Comment: I can't find `onclick` in `responsive-navbar-react` docs

Comment: Maybe you can create new `/logout` route. In logout component remove `isLoggedIn` in `localStorage` and redirect to `/home` route.

Comment: can you write the code because what will i return from the component?

Comment: You can return `null` from the component and redirect to home route

Comment: check the edit in question please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247168/discussion-between-kennarddh-and-mordor619).